# Delete Folders that are older then a year ago

Tags: linux, bash

I have these folders, where they are being sorted by the date, YYYY-MM

```
2020-01
2020-02
2020-03
...
2022-07
2022-08
2022-09
```

I would like to delete all folders that are are over a year old.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES=(
   "/tmp/test/*"
)

NOW=$( date +%s )
LAST_YEAR=$(date +“%Y-%m” -d "365 days ago")


for folder in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
   if [ -d "$folder" ]; then
      if [ $folder -gt $LAST_YEAR ]; then
          echo $( date ) $folder - DELETED
      else
         echo $( date ) $folder - SAVED
      fi
   fi
done
```

The code is giving me an error

```
This line here: 
    if [ $folder -gt $LAST_YEAR ]; then
Error Message:
   integer expression expected
```

Would anyone know how to go about deleting folders that are over a year old??
Thanks

Comment: One problem with redundant quotes : `%Y-%m` rather than `"%Y-%m"`

Comment: If the dates are correct on the folders, this can be done by just `find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +365 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Redundant quotes are not a problem. [Curly quotes are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704762), like in `date +“%Y-%m”`. [Lack of quotes may be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Also I think you don't want to quote the asterisk in `LOG_FILES=( "/tmp/test/*" )` (although not quoting `${LOG_FILES[@]}` kinda cancels this out; two questionable pieces of code kinda work together, but not necessarily not like you designed). The final problem is `-gt` in `[ … ]` compares integers only. For now I have no time for proper answer (I may be able to add one later), so just a terse comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because your folders contain minus char, do not the compararison with arithmetic operators (-gt, -lt...). Use string operators (>, <...).

If you really want to test with arithmetic, with dates in this format YMD, not DMY, you must remove minus char during comparison. Replace `$folder` with `${folder//-/}` and use `%Y%m` for your last date format.

Comment: So I add, $folder=${folder//-/} but I'm getting this error message /tmp/test/202209: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1736786 I think there is nothing in the code you posted that could print such error. Is the error from another piece of code (e.g. `rm -r "$folder"`)?

Comment: @user1736786, do not change `folder` value. Check its value like this `if [ ${folder//-/} -gt $LAST_YEAR ]; then`